# DTM counting error in R

Tags: r

I am just trying to see the number of word occurrences of a document by making a simple DTM according to a dictionary, so my code looks like :

```
library(tm)

doc <- "phone book laptop book PC"

vocab <- c('phone','book', 'laptop')

dtm_n <- DocumentTermMatrix(Corpus(VectorSource(doc)),
                            control=list(
                              dictionary=vocab) 
)
inspect(dtm_n)
```

And the result looks like this:

```
<<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 1, terms: 3)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 3/0
Sparsity           : 0%
Maximal term length: 6
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
Sample             :
    Terms
Docs book laptop phone
   1    1      1     2
```

It seems the values for words(book, phone) are somehow exchanged.

Is there a good way to fix this??

And I am new to R, so I might be missing something.

If there is.. please let me know.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just check term frequency in a vector like `doc` You can do the job in various ways. Since I have been recently using the `tidytext` package, I leave one way for you. You need a data frame when you use `unnest_tokens()`. The function split words and create a data frame in long format. Then, you count how many times each word appear in the document using `count()` from the dplyr package.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidytext)

out <- data_frame(document = 1, text = doc) %>%
       unnest_tokens(input = text, output = word) %>%
       count(word)

#    word     n
#   <chr> <int>
#1   book     2
#2 laptop     1
#3     pc     1
#4  phone     1
```

If you need to check term frequency for specific words, you can subset the result.

```
out %>%
filter(word %in% vocab)

#    word     n
#   <chr> <int>
#1   book     2
#2 laptop     1
#3  phone     1
```

Alternatively, you can use the following two functions to check term frequency.

```
table(strsplit(doc, " "))
#    .
#  book laptop     PC  phone 
#     2      1      1      1
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think this is good for the term frequency, but what I finally want to acheive is that I want to do the categorization based on model made by previous dtm(using svm), and the vocab will be the words that appeared in my previous docuements, so the doc should be in the form of DTM for prediction..I guess?. I will try converting yours into DTM, and if you have any idea why those counting errors happen. Plz let me know. Once again, thank you for your help.

Comment: @Yohan You can use `cast_dtm()` to convert a data frame to a dtm object.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I somehow made my own function for my own purpose and your code was really helpful!  Hope you have a great day!

Comment: @Yohan I am glad to hear that you found your way!